# The pros/cons of React class property initializers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With React, I know you can initialize component state like this:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
}
```

And if state needs to be initialized with props:

```
class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { this.props.count: 0 };
    }
}
```

However, using the `transform-class-properties` plugin, you can initialize state like so:

```
class Foo extends Component {
    state = { count: 0 };
}
```

Since `this` refers to the instance under class during construction, initial state can still use props: `state = { this.props.count: 0 }`

Besides the obvious benefit of less lines, I wanted to know what are some pros/cons of this syntax.

*Examples don't include binding of class methods as I know binding can be done when declaring those methods with fat arrow syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Pros:

- less code, more implicit

Con:

- you can't do any step-by-step calculations like with constructor

e.g

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)

  const z = props.x - props.y;
  const g = props.a + props.b;
  const total = z ** g;
  const shouldBeOpened = total > 1000;

  this.state = {
    shouldBeOpened,
    initialSomething: z > g,
  }
}
```

Comment: but you can include that logic as a class method as well, no? and call that method within state, like so: `initialSomething: this.shouldBeOpened(z, g)`

Comment: I'm not sure if they will are initialized at that time.

Comment: yup, you are right. tried this out myself. class methods are not initialized due to the order in which you declare state before class methods. you'd either use constructor or declare this method outside the class